# Transferring MySQL JSON data type in Go REST-API

Tags: mysql, json, go

I'm trying to set up a Go MySQL server that queries data from the database and sends it as a JSON. My database contains some columns that are in the new JSON type.

The Map struct:

```
type Map struct{
 Id int `json:"id"`
 Data string `json:"data"` //This column is stored in the database as a JSON. Which type to use here?
 Created time.Time `json:"created"`
 UserId  int `json:userid`
}
```

The function to fetch data from database

```
func GetMap(id int) Map{
 var mapId int
 var data string //which type should this be
 var userId int
 var created time.Time
 err := _getMap.QueryRow(id).Scan(&mapId, &data, &userId, &created) //getMap is a prepared query 
 mapObj := Map{Id:mapId, Data:data, UserId:userId, Created:created}

 return mapObj

}
```

When I send this data out like this

```
resp.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
resp.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
gmap := GetMap(id)

err := json.NewEncoder(resp).Encode(gmap);
```

The Data in the JSON that the client receives is formatted as a string:

`{\"field\":\"nowork\"...}`

I think the problem is caused by a wrong datatype in the struct definition, which means that the Data will be parsed in the wrong format.

I have tried to change the datatype to []uint8, interface{} and some others that I thought could be relevant, but to no avail.

Comment: use this for json encode/decode https://github.com/antonholmquist/jason. I had similar problems and I switch to that JASON and it works great.

Comment: Well, what do you know. It works like a charm! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, like pregmatch suggested in a comment, I tried using the [JASON](http://github.com/antonholmquist/jason) module to handle the JSON parse. To my great surprise, it works:

```
func GetMap(id int) Map{
  var mapId int
  var data string
  var userId int
  var created time.Time
  err := _getMap.QueryRow(id).Scan(&mapId, &data, &userId, &created)

  if (err != nil){
    log.Print(err)
  }
  dataJSON, _ := jason.NewObjectFromBytes([]byte(data))
  mapObj := Map{Id:mapId, Data:dataJSON, UserId:userId, Created:created}
  return mapObj

}
```

In the REST-client is received in the proper format:

```
{"field":"works!"...}
```